# MySQL Trigger with Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

This is my first attempt at using triggers, and I just made something quickly for test, but it gives me an error. Here is my trigger (set for AFTER INSERT)

```
IF NEW.controller = 'index' THEN
    SET @controller = 'index';
ELSE
    SET @controller = 'other';
END IF;

INSERT INTO 'logs'
    ( staff_id, table_name, table_id, controller )
VALUES
    ( NEW.staff_id, 'acl', NEW.id, @controller );
```

I get the following error:

> MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INSERT INTO 'logs'  ( staff_id, table_name, table_id,
>   controller ) VALUES   ( NEW' at line 7

What is the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this(Just remove the quotes from table name):

```
INSERT INTO logs
    ( staff_id, table_name, table_id, controller )
VALUES
    ( NEW.staff_id, 'acl', NEW.id, @controller );
```

or you may use the backticks

```
INSERT INTO `logs`
    ( staff_id, table_name, table_id, controller )
VALUES
    ( NEW.staff_id, 'acl', NEW.id, @controller );
```